# Dual boot windows 8 ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, uefi, windows-8

I finally managed to installed ubuntu. But I cannot boot win 8 now.
I searched on the forum and tried everything without any luck.

Here is the log from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1389617/

---

@LovinBuntu:
Here is the new URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1389617/

Comment: Please run Boot-Repair's `Recommended Repair` and indicate the new URL that will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your GRUB configuration includes a BIOS/legacy-style boot entry for Windows, but your system is booting in EFI mode. There are a number of ways to fix this. One is to create your own custom Windows boot entry for GRUB in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. Something like this might work:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt7)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

After creating that entry, type `sudo update-grub` to transfer it to the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. I can't guarantee that this will work, though; what works for one installation doesn't always work for another.

Another approach is to install another boot manager, such as [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) or [gummiboot.](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gummiboot) When installed as a primary boot manager, these tools will enable you to select Windows vs. GRUB, and you'll then use GRUB to select your kernel. Alternatively, either can boot a Linux kernel (version 3.3.0 or later) directly, bypassing GRUB entirely. Doing this optimally requires some reconfiguration, though; see [this page on the rEFInd documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/linux.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.intowindows.com/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu/ i find a link . and it is very good

NOTE : if answer is true ; please confirm answer

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.