# Dual Booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 - thinkpad x230

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-8, boot-repair

I am having problems getting grub to load Windows 8 properly after installing Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 8 on a solid state drive. Here's what I did:

1. Fresh install of Windows 8 using USB recovery drive (partitioned SSD for UEFI)
   -- Tested windows install and it worked fine
2. Built bootable USB with Ubuntu 12.10 64bit and installed Ubuntu
   -- Used Ubuntu's installer to partition the Windows 8 partition and install there
3. Reboot - try to load windows 8 from grub
   -- Ubuntu loads correctly;  windows load reports various problems with permissions and not being able to find files - I'll update what the actual errors are
4. Tried to fix the boot problem using boot-repair:
   -- here's the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1384522/

So, this is my first time trying to setup a dual boot system and I think that UEFI is the main culprit in getting this to work correctly. What do I need to

Comment: It looks like you may have to many partitions for MBR to handle, I ran into this while using bootcamp on my Mac. Do you ever see the windows boot logo?

Comment: David, the system is UEFI so the MBR is not used. And the disk is GPT so the partition limit is above 124.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a Windows disc this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader , until you get access to Windows
2. If the GRUB menu has disappeared, you can recover it via Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

This problem is identical to [this one,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221625/dual-boot-windows-8-ubuntu) aside from some minor differences in partitioning. (Your EFI System Partition, or ESP, is on /dev/sda2, vs. /dev/sda7 for the posted-to question, which affects the partition number in the GRUB `40_custom` entry.)

Comment: Thanks. I think I had multiple problems. I followed the answer from the above post and changed the /etc/grub.d/40_custom entry to '/dev/sda2'. After that, when I tried to boot Windows, I got a permission error. I went into the BIOS and turned secure boot off. I don't know how to get grub2 to boot windows with secure boot, but this solution works good enough for me.

Comment: If Ubuntu's GRUB is booting Ubuntu with Secure Boot enabled but not booting Windows 8 with Secure Boot enabled, then that sounds like a bug in GRUB or in the Shim loader that launches it. I recommend filing a bug report (as described at http://www.ubuntu.com/community/report-problem).